# C# CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, linq, checkedlistbox

I am trying to allow users to select a "table name" using a `CheckedListBox` called *tableCheckedListBox*. Once a user checks one or more `tableCheckedListBox` items (i.e. "table names"), a second `CheckedListBox` called *columnCheckedListBox* should populate a group of items (i.e. "column names") associated with the "table names" checked in the `tableCheckedListBox`.

I have problems populating related `columnCheckedListBox` (i.e."column names") once the user checks "table names" in `tableCheckedListBox`. (FYI - I used LINQ to SQL to create my classes that represent the "table names" in my database. The classes (i.e. "table names") populate successfully in the `tableCheckedListBox`; On the contrary, I have problems populating the properties (i.e."column names") in the classes to `columnCheckedListBox`).

Here's what I been working with.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace QueryBuilder
{
    public partial class FrmQueryBuilder : Form
    {

        public FrmQueryBuilder();
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(DBClassDataContext).GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)
                {
                    object[] attributes = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false);

                    if (attributes.Length > 0)
                    {
                        tableCheckedListBox.Items.Add(property.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void tableCheckedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] tableColumns1 = typeof(TABLENAMEONE).GetProperties();
            PropertyInfo[] tableColumns2 = typeof(TABLENAMETWO).GetProperties();
            PropertyInfo[] tableColumns3 = typeof(TABLENAMETHREE).GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo columns1 in tableColumns1)
            {
                if (columns1.PropertyType.IsClass)
                {
                    object[] colAttrib1 = columns1.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false);

                    if (colAttrib1.Length > 0)
                    {
                        tableCheckedListBox.Items.Add(columns1.Name);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (PropertyInfo columns2 in tableColumns2)
            {
                if (columns2.PropertyType.IsClass)
                {
                    object[] colAttrib2 = columns2.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false);

                    if (colAttrib2.Length > 0)
                    {
                        tableCheckedListBox.Items.Add(columns2.Name);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (PropertyInfo columns3 in tableColumns3)
            {
                if (columns3.PropertyType.IsClass)
                {
                    object[] colAttrib3 = columns3.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false);

                    if (colAttrib3.Length > 0)
                    {
                        tableCheckedListBox.Items.Add(columns3.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void columnCheckedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? You should try to narrow down the code to what is relevant to your question (i.e the error probably isn't in the empty method)

Comment: In the tableCheckedListBox method, when I instantiate one class the columnCheckedListBox method executes successfully. The problem starts when I want more than one tableCheckedListBox checked. I need help with populating multiple tableCheckedListBox column names. I hope this comment is clearer.